# C rename() can't seem to get it to work

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that takes in a database of listfile names and compare it with another list. When there is a match it should rename the file with that name to the corresponding relationNumber.

At the end of the code I try to rename the file, but it doesn't let me. Is it because I'm trying to pass chars instead of const chars? And if so, how can I solve this? Before I try to rename the file I printed the strings out to see what is in them and the strings contain; "Zaalstra legitimatie.txt" and "1.17234842.txt" which is what I want. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define relationLen 10
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define resetptr NULL

typedef int bool;

char* strcasestr(char* haystack, char* needle) {
    size_t i, j;

    if (!needle[0])
        return (char*) haystack;

    for (i = 0; haystack[i]; i++) {
        bool matches = true;

        for (j = 0; needle[j]; j++) {
            if (!haystack[i + j])
                return NULL;

            if (tolower((unsigned char)needle[j]) != tolower((unsigned char)haystack[i + j])) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matches) 
            return (char *)(haystack + i);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char database[1024][30];
    char name[30] = {0};
    char newName[30] = {0};
    char extension[1024][5];
    char lined[256], linef[256];
    char relationNumber[] = "1.1";
    char newRelationNumber[relationLen] = {0};
    char *ret, *number;
    int i, j, c, k, len = 0;

    FILE* filef = fopen("filelist.txt", "r");
    for(i = 0; (c = fgetc(filef)) != EOF; i++) {
        fgets(linef, sizeof(linef), filef);
        strcpy(database[i], (char[2]){(char) c, '\0'});
        strcat(database[i], linef);
        len = strlen(database[i]);
        for(j = 0, k = 5; j < 4; j++, k--) {
            extension[i][j] = database[i][len-k];
        }
        printf("%s ", extension[i]);
        printf("%s", database[i]);
    }

    FILE* filed = fopen("Database.txt", "r");
        fgets(lined, sizeof(lined), filed);
    printf("%s", lined);

    number = strstr(lined, relationNumber);

    for(i = 0; lined[i] != 9; i++)
        newName[i] = lined[i];
    newName[i] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i < relationLen; i++)
        newRelationNumber[i] = number[i];
    newRelationNumber[i] = '\0';


    number = resetptr;

    strcat(newRelationNumber, ".txt");
    ret = strcasestr(database[i], newName);

    printf("%s", database[0]);
    printf("%s", newRelationNumber);
    i = rename(database[0], newRelationNumber);
    printf("\n%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you limit the example to just contain the `rename()` call in a working `main()` function?

Comment: "*but it doesn't let me*" <- you need to elaborate on that. "*Is it because I'm trying to pass chars instead of const chars?*" no, that's implicitly convertible.

Comment: If `rename` returns -1 (stating that it failed), you should then call `perror` to see why it failed.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** `gdb` to run your code step by step.

Comment: Also, please read how to create a [mcve], see also @oysteijo comment.

Comment: unrelated, but you shouldn't define `true` and `false` yourself -- if you want to use these defines, include `stdbool.h`.

Comment: You probably need to add the path to the file to rename. It probably now doesn't find the file.

Comment: Read documentation of [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html). It can fail, you should test against that.

Comment: It is necessary to delete newline from the file name.

Comment: seems that you are missing `#include <ctype.h>`

Comment: At last, having huge [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) which are large data structures (arrays in your case) of several kilobytes is *very bad smell*. Use [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: `for(i = 0; (c = fgetc(filef)) != EOF; i++) {
        fgets(linef, sizeof(linef), filef);` You don't need the outer loop. fgets() returns NULL on EOF. (but you do have to remove the trailing '\n' )

Comment: Here you have `ret = strcasestr(database[i], newName);` ...and then what happens with `ret` ? Same here `newName[i] = lined[i];`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everybody. I'll read the minimal, complete and verifiable example doc first and try to re-ask it with something you guys can replicate.

Comment: THANKS JOOP. I didn't delete the trailing '\n'. Now it works! AMAZING THANKS!